# flutter only one widget can select in page

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a widget that can highlight text by tap, so I put 13 same widgets on one page. what I want to do is only one widget can highlight in some time.

```
Column(
          children: List.generate(13, (index) {
            return MySelectableText(
              data: data,
              highLight: highLight[index],
              callBack: () {
                print('fjkdsfj');
                setState(() {
                  for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
                    highLight[i] = false;
                  }
                  highLight[index] = true;
                });
              },
            );
          }),
        )

SelectableText.rich(TextSpan(
        children: List.generate(
            widget.data.length,
            (index) => TextSpan(
                text: widget.data[index] + ' ',
                style: TextStyle(
                    backgroundColor: selectIndex == index && widget.highLight
                        ? Colors.blueAccent
                        : Colors.transparent),
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () {
                    print(index.toString() + widget.highLight.toString());
                    setState(() {
                      selectIndex = index;
                      widget.callBack();
                    });
                  }))));
```

this can work, but what I want is that I do not need to maintain and set a highLight list because actually the widget num is dynamically changed.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this example to understand the logic and modify it according to your need.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DesignPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DesignPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DesignPageState createState() => _DesignPageState();
}

class _DesignPageState extends State<DesignPage> {
  int selectedItems = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:const Text("Patient List",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 16),),backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: const Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.grey,),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
            child: ClipRRect(child: Image.network("https://www.whatsappprofiledpimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Profile-Photo-Wallpaper.jpg",width: 30,height: 30,fit: BoxFit.cover,),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: List.generate(13, (index) {
          return clickableItem(index);
        }),
      ),

    );

  }

  Widget clickableItem(int index){

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){

        setState(() {
          selectedItems = index;
        });
      },
      child: Text("Text $index",style: TextStyle(backgroundColor:
        selectedItems == index ? Colors.green : Colors.white
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But in this case, won't all widgets be redrawn when clicked? Is there a way to avoid this?